# Cutting A File into Chunks in Qt

Tags: qt

Can anybody give me a hint or initial idea how may I cut a file into chunks in Qt ? Is there any particular file like java it has built in function to split. Later on I want to calculate SHA-256 hash value of each chunks. Any idea guys ??

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function for that.

1. Open the original file.
2. Open a file for the first chunk.
3. Read bytes from the original file.
4. Write bytes to the chunk file.
5. Repeat.

See [QFile documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qfile.html).